# Memory limitation of Jmeter Beanshell sampler holding many variables

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a csv file with 450K rows and 2 columns. Using the CSV data config results in `SocketException: Too many open files` error on some load generators. To get around it, I used a Beanshell sampler to read the contents of the large csv in memory just once, however when it tries to save variable # 22,770 it throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null` 
Here is my simple code -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;

BufferedReader lineReader = null;
try{
    lineReader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("${skufile}"));
    String line = null;
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null){
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        vars.put("sku_" + count, values[0]);
        vars.put("optionid_" + count, values[1]);
        log.info("Sku# "+ count + " : " +vars.get("sku_"+count));
        count++;
    }
   }catch (Throwable e) {
    log.error("Errror in Beanshell", e);
    throw e;
    }
```

I have tried using both props and vars.

Answer (score 0):

1. The error is not connected with any form of limits, take a look at line 22771 of your CSV file, it might i.e. not contain comma therefore your `values[1]` becomes `null`
2. Holding the file in memory is not the best option, I would rather recommend going for CSV Data Set Config and [increasing the maximum number of open files](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/) which might be as low as `1024` for normal user for the majority of Linux distributions. The steps are:

   - add the next lines to */etc/security/limits.conf* file

     ```
     your_user_name soft nofile 4096
     your_user_name hard nofile 65536
     ```
   - you can also run the following command to ramp-up system-wide "hard" limit

     ```
     ulimit -n 8192
     ```
3. Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). Groovy is not only compatible with latest Java language features and offers [syntax sugar](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top, [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Comment: 1. There is no error in the csv file, I did double check the values. 2. The CSV data config is being used inside a Loop controller, so with 400 threads on a single load generator, I see the error reported above. I can increase the ulimit but reading the entire file only once in memory seems like a good option